# JPA generate entities with database comments

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I'm generating Entities (domain class) using eclipse IDE in an JPA Project. I can generate domain class, but I need generate this class with comments of the database (postgreSQL).
e.g. in database I have table with name "user" and this table have the comment "Table containing user data" and this table have field with name "login" with comment "Login of the user". I Need that this class is created as:

```
/**
* Table containing user data
* 
*/
@Entity 
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** Login of the user */
    @column(name="login")
    private String login;
```

It is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside: I wouldn't employ "User" as table name. [Mixed case identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in Postgres are a constant source of confusion. And `user` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in every SQL standard and in Postgres.

Comment: Ok man, this is only an example, I do not create this tables/fields in Postgre.

Comment: The name of the database is PostgreSQL or Postgres for short. Ain't no such thing as "Postgre". I can't help with the Java problem, though, sorry.

Comment: Erwin, let us focus on solving the problems asked. What really matters is that everyone understands what I mean by "Postgre"

Comment: @vctlzac: I am commenting. If I had a solution to your problem, I would write an answer. People search for content using "postgres", which will not find "postgre". It matters.

Comment: @Erwin, the question already contains the word "postgreSQL" and is enough for search find her.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a look at [hibernate-tools.jar](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/ant.html) ANT tasks.

In case it does not support it, you could easily modify the source code (have a look at POJOClass, BasicPOJOClass, EntityPOJOClass) and/or the template responsible for the entity field generation PojoFields.ftl(which is a Freemarker template).

I do not have time to look at it in detail but I hope it helps you

Answer (score -1):

'user' table can't create, because PostgreSQL has own table named 'user'. So you have to choose anohter name.